# How to print odd numbers in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop

```
for i in {1..100}
do
    if [ ($i % 2) -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

Hi! I am learning Bash but I have some probelems with printing the odd numbers in the range 1 to 100, obviously I have some syntax error which I cannot find.

Comment: `for i in {1..100}; do (( i%2 )) && echo $i; done`

Comment: check how to use [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion)

Comment: @anubhava `seq 1 2 100` :-)

Comment: @jhnc: Why use an external utility when we can use `for ((i=1; i<=100; i+=2))` in bash :-)

Comment: @anubhava less prolix often means easier-to-spot bugs

Comment: While the answer below (`for i in {1..10..2}`) is probably the best for `bash`, your question was "where is my syntax error?". You were very close, just forgot to use double parentheses for arithmetic computation: `$((i % 2))`.

Comment: for syntax issues consider pasting your code (including the appropriate shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: @jhnc indeed, I meant that (now fixed). I wasn't even trying to answer - I had noticed the first comment already did, I only wanted to point out that the OP asked about the syntax in his attempt, not so much about the best solution.

Comment: `printf "%s\n" {1..100..2}` works.

Answer (score 12):

The `{x..y}` construct allows a 3rd argument to designate the increment value (default is 1), eg:

```
for i in {1..20..3}    # start with 1 and increment by 3 until you reach/pass 20
do
    echo $i
done
```

This generates:

```
1
4
7
10
13
16
19
```

For `odd` vs `even` you designate the starting number and increment by 2:

```
# odd numbers

for i in {1..10..2}    # start with an odd number and increment by 2
do
    echo $i
done

1
3
5
7
9

# even numbers

for i in {2..10..2}    # start with an even number and increment by 2
do
    echo $i
done

2
4
6
8
10
```

Comment: No loop needed - `printf "%s\n" {1..100..2}`

Answer (score 1):

I think your if statement isn't correct.  Here's a small rewrite with a working if:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                    
for i in {1..100}
do
    isEvenIfZero=$i%2;
    if [[ $isEvenIfZero -ne 0 ]];
    then
        #echo -n $i #single line
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

Comment: If you use the arithmetic conditional, you don't need the temp var: `if ((i % 2 == 0)); then ...`

Comment: The first echo has -n, which gets rid of the newline.  You can get rid of the second echo by getting rid of the -n in the first echo.  I like having all this on one line, but yeah, it's tighter without the second echo (I'll remove it)